# How to use GNOME tweak tool to get shell themes

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

So I'm trying to get custom shells and have tried using this as many people have recommended it. All I see in the Shell Extensions menu is "install shell extension" and when I click on the link user themes isn't there. Also, in the theme menu, there is a triangle with an exclamation mark in it next to Shell Theme. how can I fix this and get shell themes like  Faience?

Comment: Did you update your version of gnome? Some extensions are only compatible with some version of Gnome.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: yes i just looked and i do. ubuntu had some weird icon and said i had to remove some files update some files and replace some, so i did and the stuff in the shell extensions went away hence why i change my question

Answer (score 1):

To get a user specified shell theme, use this extension:
[User Themes - GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/). Install it from the extension, page and make sure it is on in [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-tweak-tool/):
[image]

and here are the results - with it off, and with it on:
[image]

You can then use [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-tweak-tool/), or [`dconf-tools`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/dconf-tools/) *(use `org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name NAME_OF_THEME`)* to set the theme - here is Gnome Tweak Tool again:

[image]

By the way, I recommend the [Zukiwi Theme](http://lassekongo83.deviantart.com/art/Zukiwi-313347909) - you may be able to install that with:

```
sudo apt-get install zukiwi
```

---

### For your [original question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/414286/revisions), as this is useful also for reference:

To fix *some* shell extension that also have the warning triangle, particularly after an update:

First, go to [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/), and see if any update icons are displayed.

If that does not work, first find your version of Gnome by running this:

```
 gnome-shell --version
```

In my case, this is `3.10.3`, but I only need the `3.10` bit.

Then open Nautilus *(File Manager)*, open the location bar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), and enter this:

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

Alternately, view hidden file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, and open `.local` > `share` > *etc*

Find the folder with the extension in - For instance, [Status are Horizontal Spacing](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/), by `mathematicalcoffee`, is in this folder:

```
status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com
```

Open up the folder, then open the file `metadata.json`. Find these lines:

```
  "shell-version": [
    "3.4", 
    "3.6", 
    "3.8"
  ],
```

and add your version of Gnome in if it is not present:

```
  "shell-version": [
    "3.4", 
    "3.6", 
    "3.8",
    "3.10"
  ],
```

Note where you need the commas `,`. Save and exit, and after reloading the shell *(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, enter <kbd>r</kbd>, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)*, the extension should work. If the warning triangle is still there, then it is probably some other problem.

Comment: So i clicked the link for the user themes and clicked the switch to on and clicked install when it asked me but nothing happens after that.... what do i do now.

Comment: Close the browser window, and reload the page - the switch should hopefully still be on to indicate it is working. You should now be able to enable the theme in [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-tweak-tool/). To work, theme be gnome-shell compatible, and in `/usr/share/themes`